How to perform AC analysis for cascode common source amplifier with resistive load?
I have designed a cascode common-source amplifier with a resistor load  between transistors 1 and 2. I would like to verify if my AC model for this circuit is correct. Additionally, I need guidance on solving the small-signal equations to relate Vout and Vin, in order to find the voltage gain .
Could someone please review my AC model and suggest the steps to derive the expression for Av?
Thank you.


Where are your simulation results. That's likely all you need to do to verify it's performance.

@Andyaka, it’s just have to do with the derivation, is the AC circuit drawn correctly?
